# $.post into a php class function

Tags: php, ajax, post

I want to make a live username check and I want to use a PHP function.

```
-->
<?php
    require '../../core/init.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>K&ouml;ppCMS - Registrieren</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/footer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#username").keyup(function (e) {

                //removes spaces from username
                $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));

                var username = $(this).val(); //get the string typed by user

                $.post('users.php', {'username':username}, function(data) { //make ajax call to users.php
                    $("#user-result").html(data); //dump the data received from PHP page
                });

            });
        });
</script>
</head>
```

Init.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database/connect.php';
require 'classes/users.php';
require 'classes/general.php';

$users         = new Users($db);
$general     = new General();

$errors     = array();
?>
```

So how can I call the `check_username` function and send the values to it?
Hope you understand my question, because my English isn't that good.

i'd tried this in the users.php:

```
<?php
$users = new Users($db);
echo $users->check_username($_POST['username']);
class Users{
    private $db;

    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->db = $database;
    }

    public function check_username($data) {
        return $data+1;
    }
    function func1($data){
        return $data+1;
    }

}
```

Get this Error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\kcms\system\cms\user\users.php on line 2
```

[image]

Comment: You want to use `return $username . " hi";` instead of `return $username + " hi";` Unless you want to do "math", but I doubt that very much ;-) (sidenote)

Comment: Oh thanks Fred -ii- ^^ So now lets solve my actually problem ^^

Comment: You're welcome. Did you check Barmar's answer?

Comment: Yes of course, but what is with my js? I want to check it live so i dont know how to introduce it :/

Comment: JS is not my strong points. I suggest you take it up with Barmar or any other answers that potentially come after. I'm a "server-side" kind of guy ;-)

Comment: Thanks anyway Fred :) Is there another way to contacte you for questions?

Comment: No, I don't leave contact information on SO. I'm purely here to help for immediate questions, unless you were a client ;-)

Comment: Before you edited your post I saw a bunch of php warnings in the second "Error" screenshot followed by the correct result of check_username.  Use the console to verify that you are posting the username via ajax, and to see what the result is.  To me it looks like you have some errors/warnings in the php which are creating unexpected text in the result sent back to $.post.  The error you are now reporting seems to be because you are visiting the users.php page directly with your browser and not posting any data to it from ajax.

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP script should do something like:

```
<?php
require('init.php'); // This contains $users = new Users($db);
echo $users->check_username($_POST['username']);
```

For using the return value in your Javascript, see

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: How can i introduce it into my js? So i can use .$ajax or .$post to check it live.

Comment: Your JS is already doing that. Whatever the PHP echoes will be in the `data` variable.

Comment: Yes but i can't define $users = new Users; in the Users class.

Comment: You don't do it inside the class, you do it in the mainline code that uses the class.

Comment: The problem ist that i'd already did it in a extra init file: 
`<?php
session_start();
require 'database/connect.php';
require 'classes/users.php';
require 'classes/general.php';

$users         = new Users($db);
$general     = new General();

$errors     = array();
?>`

Comment: That looks fine to me. You're not assigning `$users` inside the class, you're assigning it in the code that uses the class.

Comment: The init.php file will be included in all the files that are important like the classes. I'd allready include the init.php in the index where i want to check the username

Comment: could you contact me per skype or email? Skype: ingosfreunde2 email: info@koeppcms.de